# How to draw a rectangular spiral with pixels in java frame

Tags: java, user-interface

Need to draw a spiral in a frame lets say the size of 640x480. It starts from the center of the frame and goes counter clockwise with pixels of different colors.

[image]

How can I do that, without using a lot of different libraries, lets say I can use only java.awt.*;

Have tried a lot of stuff but none of it worked and I dont know why, so I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: It's been a while since I've created an AWT GUI, but I'd suggest using a `Canvas` inside a `Frame`.  If you can use Java Swing, create a drawing `JPanel` in a `JFrame`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show us what you’ve tried.  We can’t suggest a solution if we don’t know what knowledge you already have.  For example, we don’t know if you’ve ever used the Graphics class.

Comment: Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics.